# jQuery sortable, drag from static list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Not really sure of the best way to explain what I am trying to do, so I have been playing with it, please see: http://bit.ly/1Fm6qgc

I would like a list of 'widgets' which are basically li's -now I want to be able to drag these into a sortable panel, this I have working in the above example, however, when I drop a 'widget' into a sortable panel I want the 'widget' to remain in the list of widgets too, so that I can place multiple instances of the widgets into multiple sortable panels.

I hope this makes sense, if you have any other ideas on how I can achieve this then it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unsure what you mean. You want to clone the widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your goals, and I have updated your fiddle. From a semantics standpoint, the `Reusable Draggable Widgets Panel` should simply be draggable widgets, not a sortable list. This makes sense because you normally wouldn't want a user to be dragging already used/changed widgets from their own `Target Widgets Sortable Lists` back into the main `Reusable Draggable Widgets Panel`, as shown in the new fiddle. As a side note, the `Reusable Draggable Widgets Panel` does take the same helper: "clone" option, but additional care would need to be take as shown in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024766/sortable-clone-helper-not-working#answers-header), making sure that the original clone shows. But as I stated before, it makes more sense for the `Reusable Draggable Widgets Panel` to just be draggable elements, not a sort list.

Here is the updated and working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqm6/401/).

For a quick overview and explanation (js):

```
function removeHighlight(){
    // Enable all sortables
    $('.sort').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('borderColor','gray');
        $this.sortable('enable');
    });
}

function addHighlight(){
    // Check number of elements already in each sortable
    $('.sort').not(this).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.find('li:not(.l-header)').length >= 3){
            $this.css('borderColor','red');
            $this.sortable('disable');
        } else {
            $this.css('borderColor','gray');
            $this.sortable('enable');
        }
    });
}
// use both mousedown and mouseup events to handle highlighting
// and enabling/disabling of sort lists.
// Using the stop/start callbacks of sortable/draggable ui plugin
// is unreliable, even after calling list.sortable("resfresh")
$('ul.sort, ul.d-widgets').on("mousedown", addHighlight);
$('ul.sort, ul.d-widgets').on("mouseup", removeHighlight);

$( ".d-widgets li:not(.l-header)" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sort",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$( "ul.disable-highlight li:not(.l-header)" ).disableSelection();

$('.sort').sortable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    connectWith: '.sort',
    items: '> li:not(.l-header)'
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="disable-highlight d-widgets">
    <li class='l-header'>Reusable Draggable Widgets Panel</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class='disable-highlight sort'>
    <li class='l-header'>Target Widgets Sortable Lists</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class='disable-highlight sort'>
    <li class='l-header'>Target Widgets Sortable Lists</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class='disable-highlight sort'>
    <li class='l-header'>Target Widgets Sortable Lists</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.d-widgets, .sort { display:inline-block; margin:5px; border:1px solid grey; vertical-align:top; }

.d-widgets{
 background-color: #81d8d0;   
}
}
ul { min-width:60px; min-height:20px; }
li { width:50px; min-height:15px; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; cursor:move; background-color:white; }

.l-header{
    cursor:auto;
    width:80px;
    padding:4px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

**EDIT** for destroying widgets:

As I stated in my comment, from a ux standpoint, an area specifically designated to deleting widgets would be a great approach as shown in my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqm6/402/).

Comment: Perfect thanks for the additional info, I wouldn't mind users being able to drag the widgets back into the main panel as a way of removing the widgets, as long as they didn't create duplicates.

Comment: For deleting, I consider creating a specific droppable designated for destroying an unwanted widget. I would do this so a user would easily understand that the desired widget would be completely removed. Also, then you don't have to worry about the duplicates issue you were referring too. See my updated fiddle in my edits above.